# Find the locus of points $P$ such that $\Delta A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}\sim\Delta A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an  triangle and let $P$ be a point in its interior. Let $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$ be projections of $P$ onto triangle sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$, respectively. and $AP\cap BC=A_{2},BP\cap AC=B_{2},CP\cap AB=C_{2}$,Find the locus of points $P$ such that $\Delta A_{1}B_{1}C_{1}\sim\Delta A_{2}B_{2}C_{2}$

It is clear $P$ is orthocenter is hold,have other point?
 the simaler problem it help to solev [Geomtry](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1243902p6368189)

Answer (score 6):

In other terms, you are looking for the locus of points such that the pedal triangle is similar to the cevian triangle. [It has been proved by Ehrmann](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2003volume3/FG200310.ps) that the orthocenter is the only point with such a property.